# Change-making: Dynamic Programming

Tags: dynamic-programming

In a lecture earlier, we were told that using a greedy approach to solve a change making problem would not always work.

An example of this was given as follows:

We want to reach `n = 14`, and we have three coins of different values: `d1 = 1`,`d2 = 7`,`d3 = 10`.

Using the greedy approach this would lead us to do `10 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1` (5 coins).

It was said the a dynamic problem approach would solve this accurately. I tried working it out but it came back to 5.

Assume F holds the number of coins needed to make an amount

```
F[14] = min {F[14 – 1] , F[14 – 7],  F[14 – 10]} + 1

      = F[14 – 10] + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5
```

This shows again that we need 5 coins, when this can clearly be done by using 2 coins (7 + 7).

What gives? Thanks.

Comment: F[14] = min {F[14 – 1] , F[14 – 7],  F[14 – 10]} + 1

      = F[14 – 10] + 1 = 4 + 1 = 5
shouldn't this be
F[14] = min {F[14 – 1] , F[14 – 7],  F[14 – 10]} + 1

      = F[14 – 7] + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assumed that `min {F[14 – 1] , F[14 – 7],  F[14 – 10]}=F[14-10]` when it is not the case. The minimum is actually `F[14-7]=1` and hence the optimum is `2`

Comment: Why is that? I thought the min was a function that took the smallest result. In this case, 14 - 10 is the smallest number, smaller then 14 - 7. What am I not understanding? Thanks

Comment: @Pete The minimum function gets the smalles value of F, NOT the argument inside F. F[13] means is the least number of coins to make change for 13. This would be to get one from d3, 3 from d1, for a total of 4 coins.  F[14-7]=F[7] is the minimum number of coins to make change for 7. in this case, its ONLY one coin, d2. For F[14-10]=F[4]. You need 4 from d1 to make change to 4. So the minimum of all of these is F[7], NOT F[14-10]